# How to customize the opening and closing brackets in `siunitx`?

Tags: siunitx

It seems `siunitx` options `open-bracket` and `close-bracket` no longer work. Is it possible to get such functionalities back?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

    \usepackage{calc}
    
    
    % ========== Units and precision packages ==========
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    
            % complex numbers options
% BEGIN_FOLD
    
                \sisetup{complex-root-position=before-number, input-complex-root=ij}
                \newlength{\widthOperatorJSeparator}
                \setlength{\widthOperatorJSeparator}{\widthof{$\,$}}
                \sisetup{output-complex-root=\mathit{j}\hspace{0.11\widthOperatorJSeparator}}   
                
% END_FOLD
    
            % brackets options
% BEGIN_FOLD
    
                \sisetup{bracket-numbers=true, open-bracket=], close-bracket=]}

% END_FOLD



\begin{document}

\complexqty{11 + j11}{\ohm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe this is an oversight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is an oversight and that there should be an option for setting the brackets. Something like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { siunitx }
 {
  output-complex-bracket-open .tl_set:N = \l__siunitx_complex_bracket_open_tl,
  output-complex-bracket-close .tl_set:N = \l__siunitx_complex_bracket_close_tl,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% complex numbers options
\sisetup{
  complex-root-position=before-number,
  input-complex-root=ij,
  output-complex-root=\mathit{j}\mspace{1mu},
  bracket-numbers=true,
  output-complex-bracket-open=[,
  output-complex-bracket-close=],
}

\begin{document}

\complexqty{11 + j11}{\ohm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The option names might be not the preferred ones. The spacing for the *j* is much easier to obtain and customize.

Answer (score 3):

`siunitx` v3 has removed options `open-bracket` and `close-bracket` and now use of these options raise warnings.

```tex
Package siunitx Warning: Option "close-bracket" has been removed in this
(siunitx)                release.
Package siunitx Warning: Option "open-bracket" has been removed in this
(siunitx)                release.
```

The removal is done in [commit `c077c15`](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/commit/c077c15a9345fd2d7df3ed468df526ed7d6093fd), with message

> Remove options for open/close brackets
>
> This makes them purely internal:
> can be reversed later if required.

You can open an issue to https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx, as another workaround, load `siunitx` v2 using `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`.